# extract names from string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string

I have a string as:

```
s="(2021-07-29 01:00:00 AM BST)  
---  
peter.j.matthew has joined the conversation  
  
  

(2021-07-29 01:00:00 AM BST)  
---  
john cheung has joined the conversation  
  
  


(2021-07-29 01:11:19 AM BST)  
---  
allen.p.jonas  
Hi, james  
  
  
(2021-07-30 12:51:16 AM BST)  
---  
karren wenda  
how're you ? 
  
  
  
---  
  
* * *"
```

I want to extract the names as:

> names_list= ['allen.p.jonas','karren wenda']

what I have tried:

> names_list=re.findall(r'---  [\S\n](\D+  [\S\n])',s)

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you want to find names on whose lines do *not* end with the text `has joined the conversation`:

```py
names = re.findall(r'\(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M [A-Z]{3}\)\s+---\s+\r?\n((?:(?!\bhas joined the conversation).)+?)[ ]*\r?\n', s)
print(names)  # ['allen.p.jonas', 'karren wenda']
```

The salient portion of the regex is this:

```regex
((?:(?!\bhas joined the conversation).)+?)[ ]*\r?\n
```

This captures a name without matching `has joined the conversation` by using a tempered dot trick.  It matches one character at a time on the line containing the name, making sure that the `conversation` text does not appear anywhere, until reaching the CR?LF at the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks tim. This seems work for me `---  [\S\n]((\b\S+\b  ))` but not for the names with spaces as it captures `allen.p.jones` but not `karren wenda`. Can you help?

Comment: If my pattern is already working, why would you want to change it?

Comment: I want names that are not followed by `has joined the conversation` only.

Comment: @new_learner OK...check the updated answer in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to match `['allen.p.jonas','karren wenda']`, you can use match a non whitespace char after it on the next line:

```
^---[^\S\n]*\n(\S.*?)[^\S\r\n]*\n\S
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `---` Match `---`
- `[^\S\n]*\n` Match optional spaces and a newline
- `(\S.*?)` Capture **group 1** (*returned by re.findall*) match a non whitespace char followed by as least as possible chars
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match optional whitespace chars without a newline
- `\n\S` Match a newline and a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VjRTvS/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/hwp6B1)

For example

```
print(re.findall(r"^---[^\S\n]*\n(\S.*?)[^\S\r\n]*\n\S", s, re.M))
```

Output

```
['allen.p.jonas', 'karren wenda']
```

---

To explicitly exclude lines that contain `has joined the conversation` you can use a negative lookahead:

```
^---[^\S\n]*\n(?!.*\bhas joined the conversation\b)(\S.*?)[^\S\r]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E3WCiN/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/8FC1N0)

For example:

```
print(re.findall(r"^---[^\S\n]*\n(?!.*\bhas joined the conversation\b)(\S.*?)[^\S\r]*$", s, re.M))
```

Output

```
['allen.p.jonas', 'karren wenda']
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you want to match names that are *not* followed by "has joined the conversation":

```
name_pattern = re.compile(r'---\s*\n(\w(?:[\w\. ](?!has joined the conversation))*?)\s*\n', re.MULTILINE)
print(re.findall(name_pattern, s))
```

Explanation:

- `---\s*\n` matches the dashes possibly followed by whitespaces and a required new line
- Then comes our matching group composed of:

  - `\w` starts with a 'word' character (a-Z, 0-9 or _)
  - `(?:[\w\. ](?!has joined the conversation))*?` a non capturing group of  repeating `\w`, `.` or whitespace *not* followed by "has joined the conversation". The capturing goes on until the next whitespace or new line. (`*?` makes the expression lazy instead of greedy)

Output:

```
['allen.p.jonas', 'karren wenda']
```